# Reopen "dream job and bad written test"

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[Interviewed for dream job, bad written test: how can I recover?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/104191/interviewed-for-dream-job-bad-written-test-how-can-i-recover/104204) was closed as too broad and then edited.  The current version of the question is answerable, in scope, and not too broad.  Let's reopen it.

Comment: 2nd VTRO cast :)

Comment: I voted (both nationally, and here). ;-)

Comment: I find it sad that this old question was closed in the first place and required a Meta plea to get it reopened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Casted the 5th and final vote and the post is open again now.

Comment: Good work...,,,..